# How to minify sencha touch 2.1 + cordova/phonegap 2.2.0 app developed with Netbeans?

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans, sencha-touch, apk

While developing an app based on sencha touch 2.1 and cordova/phonegap 2.2.0, I have noticed a strange behavior by netbeans.

When my App become bigger, I started to use sencha cmd (3.0.0.250) to minify (production build) my js-css-html code. So I created a batch file and added it to the build.xml (pre-compile). I also edited the activity class to point to the sencha cmd build output. So in the `Assets/www` path there is my "readable" js, html, ... code and also the minified code.

Now When I build the app, the apk file is up to 8mb.

But when I delete the "readable" js-html-css code before build (also don't use a batch script) then the size of my apk is only 600kb.

In both cases the performance is the same.

Is this a normal behavior of Netbeans? How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i understand this behavior. all files within assets/www are put into apk.

my project included all (sencha stuff, phonegap stuff). i think splitting them is better. Now i have a project, that containing the js/html/css stuff - e.g. fast debugging with chrome. for every target platform i have a own project (using for build). e.g. android-10, android-15, ios ... i make us of some ant pre-compile commands to first build sencha, than copy output and finally build the apps.